# I cant receive an HTTP POST request correctly

Tags: php

I have some code that is supposed to process a POST request that is sent to the page. Whenever I try to send the post request to the file outside of WordPress it works flawlessly. However, whenever I try to send a POST request to the code while in WordPress it gets processed but says that it's an incorrect username and password.

Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php

// Load Request
$api_method = isset($_POST['api_method']) ? $_POST['api_method'] : '';
$api_data = isset($_POST['api_data']) ? $_POST['api_data'] : '';

// Validate Request
if (empty($api_method) || empty($api_data)) {
    API_Response(true, 'Invalid Request');
}
if (!function_exists($api_method)) {
    API_Response(true, 'API Method Not Implemented');
}

// Call API Method
call_user_func($api_method, $api_data);

/* Helper Function */

function API_Response($isError, $errorMessage, $responseData = '')
{
    exit(json_encode(array(
        'IsError' => $isError,
        'ErrorMessage' => $errorMessage,
        'ResponseData' => $responseData
    )));
}

/* API Methods */

function loginUser($api_data)
{
    // Decode Login Data
    $login_data = json_decode($api_data);

    // Dummy Check
    if ($login_data->username == 'test' &&
        $login_data->password == '1234')
    {
        // Success
        API_Response(false, '', 'SUCCESS');
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
        API_Response(true, 'Invalid username and/or password.');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code will run any function I tell it to in a POST request. This is extremely dangerous and insecure. You should not use this under any circumstances. If you want to receive POST requests on your WordPress site, create a REST API endpoint: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have looked at creating a rest endpoint and it looks confusing. Do you think there is another way?